# How to store strings with space into one var?

Tags: c, string, barcode, scanf

I am new to C and now I am working with FILE
Lets say that i have a file named data.txt and it contains this stuff

```
4536279|Chocolate Bar|23|1.99
3478263|Chips|64|3.44
4245553|4% Milk|12|3.99

1st field is BAR CODE
2nd field is PRODUCT NAME
3rd field is QUANTITIES
4th field is PRICE
```

and they are separated by pipe (|)

When then user enter the bar code (for example 3478263)

1. I have to store it into a variable
2. then store the product name in a STRING variable
3. store the QUANTITIES in a int variable
4. store the PRICE in a double variable

i know how to do the 1st line but i dont know how to scan the file for the barcode..

```
int bar=0;
int upc=0;
inv=fopen("data.txt", "r");

printf("Enter barcode: ");
scanf("%d", bar);
do {
    fscanf(inv, "%d", &upc);
    printf(" UPC: %d", upc);

} while (bar != upc);
```

Comment: the problem is i dont know how to store the PRODUCT NAME in to one stings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a way like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct record {
    int barcode;          //1st field is BAR CODE
    char product_name[32];//2nd field is PRODUCT NAME
    int quantities;       //3rd field is QUANTITIES
    double price;         //4th field is PRICE
} Record;

int main(void){
    FILE *fin = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    Record rec;
    int ent_barcode, bar_code;

    printf("Enter barcode: ");
    scanf("%d", &ent_barcode);

    while(fscanf(fin, "%d", &bar_code)==1){
        if(ent_barcode == bar_code){
            rec.barcode = bar_code;
            if(3==fscanf(fin, "|%31[^|]|%d|%lf", rec.product_name, &rec.quantities, &rec.price))
                break;
        }
        fscanf(fin, "%*[^\n]");
    }
    fclose(fin);
    printf("barcode:%d, product name:%s, quantities:%d, price:%g\n",
           rec.barcode, rec.product_name, rec.quantities, rec.price);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do u have space next to " %d" in while(fscanf(fin, " %d", &bar_code)==1)?

Comment: @user2628078 ah, There is no need it . I've written in the manner of habit.
sorry, updated.

Comment: @user2628078 It will skip the input of characters up to the end of the line(newline).

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229907/c-parsing-string-question) answer for string parsing. You should be able to achieve your purpose. You can store the string in a char* variable. Basically it is an array of characters. Space is also a character and you can simple store it like any other character in the string. I hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on the `strtok` function for jobs like this. It helps you to split a string into tokens.

On the first sight the functioning of `strtok` seems a bit odd. First you have to call the function with the string you want to split and the column delimiter(s) to initialize parsing. The return value of this first call is the content of the first column already.

On subsequent calls you have to call `strtok` like this

```
 ret = strtok(NULL, "|");
```

Since `strtok` was initialized with a string and saves his state internally it knows how to continue. After reaching the last column `strtok` returns `NULL`.

An implementation of your problem that uses `strtok` could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *text[] = { "4536279|Chocolate Bar|23|1.99",
    "3478263|Chips|64|3.44",
    "4245553|4% Milk|12|3.99",
    NULL
};

char *column[] = { "barcode", "name", "quantity", "price" };

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *ret, *str;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; text[i] != NULL; i++) {
        str = strdup (text[i]);
        ret = strtok (str, "|");

        for (j = 0; ret != NULL; j++) {

            printf ("%10s: %s\n", column[j], ret);
            ret = strtok (NULL, "|");

        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program's output is:

```
   barcode: 4536279
      name: Chocolate Bar
  quantity: 23
     price: 1.99

   barcode: 3478263
      name: Chips
  quantity: 64
     price: 3.44

   barcode: 4245553
      name: 4% Milk
  quantity: 12
     price: 3.99
```